# Which version is the latest?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have this *little* class for parsing, comparing and sorting semantic versions. I did my best to implement the specification at [semver.org](http://semver.org) with one exception - it doesn't support the *build metadata*. Now you can tear it apart ;-)

*I removed all parameter checks to make it shorter.*

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString(),nq}")]
public class SemanticVersion : IComparable<SemanticVersion>, IComparer<SemanticVersion>
{
    private SemanticVersion() { }

    public SemanticVersion(int major, int minor, int patch, IEnumerable<string> labels = null)
    {            
        Labels = labels?.ToList();
    }

    public static SemanticVersion Parse(string value)
    {
        var versionMatch = Regex.Match(value, @"v?(?<major>\d+)\.(?<minor>\d+)\.(?<patch>\d+)(-(?<labels>.+))?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!versionMatch.Success)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new SemanticVersion
        {
            Major = int.Parse(versionMatch.Groups["major"].Value),
            Minor = int.Parse(versionMatch.Groups["minor"].Value),
            Patch = int.Parse(versionMatch.Groups["patch"].Value),
            Labels = versionMatch.Groups["labels"].Value.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
        };
    }

    public int Major { get; private set; }

    public int Minor { get; private set; }

    public int Patch { get; private set; }

    public List<string> Labels { get; private set; }

    public bool IsPrerelease => Labels?.Count > 0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var versionNumber = $"{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}";
        if (Labels.Count > 0)
        {
            versionNumber = $"{versionNumber}-{string.Join(".", Labels)}";
        }
        return versionNumber;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var semVer = obj as SemanticVersion;
        if (ReferenceEquals(semVer, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ToString() == semVer.ToString();
    }

    public int Compare(SemanticVersion x, SemanticVersion y)
    {
        const int less = -1;
        const int equal = 0;
        const int greater = 1;

        if (object.Equals(x, null) && object.Equals(y, null))
        {
            return equal;
        }

        if (object.Equals(x, null))
        {
            return less;
        }

        if (object.Equals(y, null))
        {
            return greater;
        }

        // Precedence MUST be calculated by separating the version into:
        // major, minor, patch and pre-release identifiers in that order.
        // (Build metadata does not figure into precedence).

        var xVersions = new[] { x.Major, x.Minor, x.Patch };
        var yVersions = new[] { y.Major, y.Minor, y.Patch };

        // Precedence is determined by the first difference
        // when comparing each of these identifiers from left to right.
        // Example: 1.0.0 < 2.0.0 < 2.1.0 < 2.1.1.
        var versionDifferences = xVersions.Zip(yVersions, (xv, yv) => xv.CompareTo(yv));
        var firstVersionDifference = versionDifferences.FirstOrDefault(diff => diff != 0);
        if (firstVersionDifference != 0)
        {
            return firstVersionDifference;
        }

        // When major, minor, and patch are equal, 
        // a pre-release version has lower precedence than a normal version. 
        // Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0.

        if (x.IsPrerelease && !y.IsPrerelease)
        {
            return less;
        }

        if (!x.IsPrerelease && y.IsPrerelease)
        {
            return greater;
        }

        // Precedence for two pre-release versions with the same major, minor, and patch version 
        // MUST be determined by comparing each dot separated identifier from left to right 
        // until a difference is found as follows:     

        var labelComparer = new LabelComparer();
        var labelDiffs = x.Labels.ZipWithDefault(y.Labels, (l1, l2) => labelComparer.Compare(l1, l2));
        var firstLabelDiff = labelDiffs.FirstOrDefault(diff => diff != 0);

        return firstLabelDiff;
    }

    public int CompareTo(SemanticVersion other)
    {
        return Compare(this, other);
    }

    public static explicit operator SemanticVersion(string semVer)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(semVer) ? null : Parse(semVer);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(SemanticVersion semVer)
    {
        return semVer.ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator <(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        return semVer1.CompareTo(semVer2) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        return semVer1.CompareTo(semVer2) > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(semVer1, semVer2))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(semVer1, null) || ReferenceEquals(semVer2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return semVer1.CompareTo(semVer2) == 0;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        return !(semVer1 == semVer2);
    }

    public static bool operator <=(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        return semVer1 < semVer2 || semVer1 == semVer2;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(SemanticVersion semVer1, SemanticVersion semVer2)
    {
        return semVer1 > semVer2 || semVer1 == semVer2;
    }
}
```

To compare the labels I use this comparer:

```
internal class LabelComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        const int less = -1;
        const int equal = 0;
        const int greater = 1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) && ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return equal;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        {
            return less;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return greater;
        }

        // Identifiers consisting of only digits are compared numerically.
        if (x.IsNumeric() && y.IsNumeric())
        {
            return int.Parse(x).CompareTo(int.Parse(y));
        }

        // Identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII sort order.
        if (!x.IsNumeric() && !y.IsNumeric())
        {
            return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }

        // Numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric identifiers.
        return x.IsNumeric() ? less : greater;
    }
}
```

With this extension I determine if a string is numeric:

```
internal static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string value) 
        => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^\d+$");
}
```

This extension helps me to zip **all** labels:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipWithDefault<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first)); }
    if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second)); }
    if (resultSelector == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector)); }

    using (var enumeratorFirst = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumeratorSecond = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var isEndOfFirst = !enumeratorFirst.MoveNext();
        var isEndOfSecond = !enumeratorSecond.MoveNext();
        while (!isEndOfFirst || !isEndOfSecond)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(
                isEndOfFirst ? default(TFirst) : enumeratorFirst.Current,
                isEndOfSecond ? default(TSecond) : enumeratorSecond.Current);

            isEndOfFirst = !enumeratorFirst.MoveNext();
            isEndOfSecond = !enumeratorSecond.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

---

These two tests verify the correct order:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Sort_WithoutLabels()
{
    // 1.0.0 < 2.0.0 < 2.1.0 < 2.1.1.

    var actual = new[]
    {
        "2.1.0",
        "2.0.0",
        "2.1.1",
        "1.0.0",
    }
    .Select(SemanticVersion.Parse)
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToList();

    var expected = new[]
    {
        "1.0.0",
        "2.0.0",
        "2.1.0",
        "2.1.1",
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Sort_WithLabels()
{
    // Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.

    var actual = new[]
    {
        "1.0.0-beta.11",
        "1.0.0-alpha.beta",
        "1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "1.0.0-rc.1",
        "1.0.0-alpha",
        "1.0.0-beta.2",
        "1.0.0-beta",
        "1.0.0",
    }
    .Select(SemanticVersion.Parse)
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToList();

    var exptected = new[]
    {
        "1.0.0-alpha",
        "1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "1.0.0-alpha.beta",
        "1.0.0-beta",
        "1.0.0-beta.2",
        "1.0.0-beta.11",
        "1.0.0-rc.1",
        "1.0.0",
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(exptected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The regular expression for parsing should be stricter. Currently it allows `01.01.1970-born in the USA™`, but it shouldn't.
- There is no need for the `IgnoreCase` option.
- Your code is generally inefficient. The methods `Equal`, `HashCode` and `Compare` should not need any memory allocations, as far as possible.
- Since a version is an immutable type, `HashCode` and `ToString` should be precomputed.
- Do not call methods like `x.IsNumeric` twice. Instead, save the result.
- Do not make your private extension methods public.
- The operator `<=` can be easily implemented doing only a single comparison.
- The `Labels` property must return an `IReadOnlyList` instead of a (possibly modifiable) `List`.
- In Java, the `compare` methods expects its arguments to never be null. If C# has the same convention, you can omit some code.
- In `Compare`, instead of the many `if` clauses, you can write `int r = x.Major.CompareTo(y.Major)`,nfollowed by `if (r != 0) return r`.

Comment: You could have added it to your other review - anyway thx ;-)

Comment: A separate answer seems justified: one addresses the main code, the other talks about testing.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `Sort` in unit tests, since that only tests very few cases. (Remember, sort algorithms are designed to use as few comparisons as possible.) Instead, make a list of elements you want to compare. Then, compare each element to each element, including itself.

When you arrange the elements in ascending order, comparing `elements[i]` with `element[j]` must have these results:

- if `i ≤ j`, compare must return `≤ 0`, in most cases `< 0`
- if `i = j`, compare must return `0`
- if `i ≥ j`, compare must return `≥ 0`, in most cases `> 0`

The above checks ensure that the `Compare` function is well-behaved.

When building a utility class for this purpose, it could look like this:

```
ComparatorTester.For(comparator)
    .Next("0.0.0")
    .SameAsAbove("00.00.00", "0.000.000")
    .Next("0.0.1")
    .Next("1.0.0")
    .AssertAllOrdered();
```

This way, your unit test contains only a single but comprehensive list of version numbers and their intended relative order. Currently you have two separate lists.

Comment: I'll be using `OrderBy` later where I actually need to order the versions (looking for the latest) - that's why I thought it was a good idea to use it for testing as well. I have other tests testing the `<>=` operators too but there are many of them so I just included the two that do the sorting.